# Dynamic Graph in android

Tags: android, graph

I have a static chart and I would like transform in a dynamic graph. How can I do? This is the code:

MainActivity

```
 public void lineGraphHandler (View view)
{
    LineGraph line = new LineGraph();
    Intent lineIntent = line.getIntent(this);
    startActivity(lineIntent);
}
```

LineGraph

```
public class LineGraph{

public Intent getIntent(Context context) {

    Random r = new Random();
    Random a = new Random();

    // Our first data
    int[] x = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }; // x values!
    int[] y =  {29, 30, 34, 45, 57, 77, 89, 100, 111 ,123 ,145 }; // y values!
    TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Line1"); 
    for( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {

        int i1 = r.nextInt(80 );
        int i2 = a.nextInt(80 );
        series.add(i1, i2);


    }



    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(series);


    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(); // Holds a collection of XYSeriesRenderer and customizes the graph
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer(); // This will be used to customize line 1
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer(); // This will be used to customize line 2
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);

    mRenderer.setChartTitle("EMG signal");
    mRenderer.setXTitle("t [s]");
    mRenderer.setYTitle("A [mV]");
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);  
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(50);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(35);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(26);
    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(30);
    mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    mRenderer.setXAxisMax(1);
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);

    // Customization time for line 1!
    renderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setLineWidth(15);
    renderer.setFillPoints(true);




    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer, "Line Graph Title");
    return intent;

}

}
```

Coordinate Data I would like to take them dall'activity main and pass them to the second main activity.
Thanks.